# How to scale and distribute the SOLR CLOUD nodes

Tags: solr

I have initially setup the SOLR CLOUD with two solr nodes as shown below.

[image]

I have to add a new solr node (i.e) with additional shard and same number of replicas with the existing SOLR CLUSTER nodes.

I have already gone through the SOLR scaling and distributing https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Introduction+to+Scaling+and+Distribution

But the above link contains information of scaling only for SOLR standalone mode. That's the sad part.

I have started the SOLR CLUSTER nodes using the following command

```
./bin/solr start -c -s server/solr -p 8983 -z [zkip's] -noprompt
```

Kindly share the command command for creating the new shard for adding new node.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge am sharing this answer.

> Adding a new SOLR CLOUD /SOLR CLUSTER node is that having the copy of
>   all the SHARDs into the new box(through replication of all SHARDs).

`SHARD` : The actual data is equally splitted across the number of SHARDs we create (while creating the collection). 
        So while adding the new SOLR CLOUD node make sure that all the SHARD should be available on the new node(RECOMENDED) or as required.

### Naming Standards of SOLR CORE in SOLR CLOUD MODE/ CLUSTER MODE

### Syntax:

```
<COLLECTION_NAME>_shard<SHARD_NUMBER>_replica<REPLICA_NUMBER>
```

### Example

```
CORE NAME : enter_2_shard1_replica1

COLLECTION_NAME : enter_2
SHARD_NUMBER : 1
REPLICA_NUMBER : 1
```

### STEPS FOR ADDING THE NEW SOLR CLOUD/CLUSTER NODE

1. Create a core with the common collection name as we used in the existing SOLR CLOUD nodes.
2. Notes while creating a new core in new node

`Example` :

```
enter_2_shard1_replica1
enter_2_shard1_replica2
```

From the above example the maximum value/number of repilca of the corresponding shard is 2(enter_2_shard1_replica2)

So in the new node while creating a core, give the replica numbering as 3 "`enter_2_shard1_replica3`" so that SOLR will take this as the third replication of the corresponding SHARD.

`Note` : replica numbering should be in a incremental oreder of 1

3. Give time to replicate the data from the existing node to the new node.